# How to get a LinkedIn Group Post "content" through API, not just the title

Tags: linkedin-api

When starting a Group Discussion through the LinkedIn website you can enter a postTitle and (optional) postText

However when querying this post through the LinkedIn API only the "title" is returned.

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{post-id}`

Tested from https://apigee.com/console/linkedin to confirm it wasn't just my script with issues.

Is there an extra parameter I can pass to the API to get this "text" field on a Group Discussion post?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the field selectors to specify the particular fields that you want returned from your call.

For example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/12345:(id,name,site-group-url,posts:(id,summary,creator))
```

Please also note that as of May 12th, 2015, the API endpoint for Groups will no longer be publicly available.  See the following blog post for more details:  https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Comment: Ah! That's the documentation I was after. Thank you. Although with the upcoming change I'm not sure it's worth the time continuing with this app. Can a small time developer like myself become "approved" for API access? I'm extending an existing app to support LinkedIn ( http://simplesocialinbox.com )

Comment: I'm not using this api call. It gives me a "Access to groups denied" error.